# Calculating Minutes between two times using TableAdapter C# [sql]

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2003

I want to calculate minutes between two times, I am generating method using TableAdapter.

I am trying with this

```
SELECT        
   name, signin, 
   DATEDIFF([minute], signin, [DateTime].Now) AS Expr1
FROM            
   Table1
```

This should calculate minute between the current time and the previous time

Comment: i am using MS-Access 2003

Comment: Tip for future questions: **always** put an appropriate tag on your question to indicate **what system** you're using - not just `sql` (that's too generic), but specify what database you're using. That helps other help you!

Comment: ok, the error is "No value given for one or more required parameter" @marc_s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct text for this query should be

```
SELECT        
   name, signin, 
   DateDiff('n',signin,Now()) as MinuteDifference
FROM            
   Table1
```

To represent the difference in minutes to the [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) function you use the shortcut 'n' (between single quotes) and do not prefix the Now() function with the DateTime word. This is totally unknown to the Access Engine